# how to convert byte array to image in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am getting byte array from api and i have applied image tag on my HTML page as `<img src="data:{{model.asd_logo_type}};base64,{{model.dfgh_logo}}" alt="...">`

but i am not able to get the image on display.

Please suggest what can i do.

Comment: try model.dfgh_logo.join()

Comment: Have you considered that your type and binary code are broken or have typo? Have you seen how img tag looks like in dev tools?

Answer (score 5):

you can use src directive to display image in angular

```
<img [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+model.dfgh_logo" />
```

This is how I achieved. `model.dfgh_logo` this should have image in byte array.

Comment: please try updated answer. If this doesn't work then please let me know which value you are getting in this variable model.asd_logo_type

Comment: in logo type i am getting "image/jpeg" and in model.dfgh_logo i am getting "blob data in buffer"

Comment: This worked for me. I have no idea what's up with the down votes