# convert byte array to image in angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, ipfs

I have sent the image file in a byte array from the server.  Now I have to convert that into a `jpeg` file and display it in a webpage.

**Code:**

```
app.get('/getPhoto/:hash',function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.hash);
    invoke = require('/Users/sanjeev.natarajan/ipfs/file1.js');

    invoke.getfile(req.params.hash).then((str)=>{
        console.log("resu",str)

        res.send({"Result":str});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.send({"Error":"error in fetching the file through the hashcode"});
    })    
});
```

I am receiving the data from the backend; now I need to convert this into an image in angular6

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Does this help you maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781966/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-image-in-angular2

Comment: no that answer doesnt work because i am sending the buffer data to front end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a byte array to a Base64-encoded string using the [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) function, and then use a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) to display the image. You will need to known the image's MIME type though:

```
var bytes = [ ... ]; // get from server
var uints = new UInt8Array(bytes);
var base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode(null, uints));
var url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64; // use this in <img src="..."> binding
```

Comment: @SanjeevKumar which error exactly and where? I assume you replaced the `[...]` placeholder with actual code that gets the byte array from server?

Comment: @SanjeevKumar sorry, my bad - please see the updated answer

Comment: The btoa function expects an array of number, not an Uint8Array. How to solve this?